# Find differences exist in A but not B

Tags: bash

This is `A`:

```
SomeFollowingText 12-45-78-54 1.1.1.1
SomeFollowingText 78-56-14-54 2.2.2.2
SomeFollowingText 52-12-98-ab 3.3.3.3
SomeFollowingText 89-za-gg-99 4.4.4.4
```

This is `B`:

```
78-56-14-54
ab-g2-ax-47
52-12-98-ab
g2-47-n7-o9
56-13-z8-ab
```

The expected output:

```
SomeFollowingText 12-45-78-54 1.1.1.1
SomeFollowingText 89-za-gg-99 4.4.4.4
```

This is my failed attempt:

```
awk '{print $2}' /home/path/A | while read line
do
    if [ "grep $line /home/path/B" != "$line" ]
    then
        echo $line
    fi
done >> /home/path/non-match
```

But the `non-match` contains the whole `A`.

I also tried this:

```
cat /home/path/A | while read line
do
    if [ "$(grep $line /home/path/B)" != "$line | awk '{print $2}'" ]
    then
        echo $line
    fi
done >> /home/path/non-match
```

Comment: `grep -vf B A` ?

Comment: @tshiono thanks, but how does it differentiate columns? Maybe the first column isn't the same for all. I got the expected result but just asking if it works in the future based on specific column

Comment: What is the expected outcome, if _SomeFollowingText_ for some line in A happens to contain _78-56-14-54_  as substring?

Comment: If the first  line in B would be only _56-14-54 2.2.2.2_, should the second line from A still be eliminated (excluded)?

Comment: @user1934428 I didn't understand your first question regarding `A containing 78-56-14-54 as substring`. The format of both file is fixed as in the question (in fact I change the format of both file to this so that I can process it better and I remove the unwanted texts in the real file).

Comment: I asked because you are using substring matching in your code (i.e. you are testing whether $line is contained somewhere as a substring in the file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next} !($2 in a)' B A
SomeFollowingText 12-45-78-54 1.1.1.1
SomeFollowingText 89-za-gg-99 4.4.4.4
```

Answer (score 1):

`if [ "grep $line /home/path/B" != "$line" ]` compares two strings, one is e.g. `grep 12-45-78-54 /home/path/B` and the other is `12-45-78-54`. Those will *always* be different.

What you apparently want to do is compare the *output* of the grep command to `$line`, so you should use `if [ "$(grep $line /home/path/B)" != "$line" ]` instead.

However, this will not give you the expected output, since you effectively deleted the 1st and 3rd token from each input line using `awk` and you can't recover those from within the loop.

A much simpler approach to your problem would be `grep -vf B A >non-match`, as @tshiono suggested.

Comment: Thanks, how can I print the whole line not matches, like the expected output? I mean what if I change the `awk` to `cat`? I tried but didn't get the expected

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if grep works exactly for one specific column.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily in `awk`:

```
awk '(NR==FNR) {b[$1]=$1}; (NR>FNR && ! b[$2]) {print}' /home/path/B /home/path/A >/home/path/non-match
```

Explanation: `awk` reads through all lines in all supplied input files (/home/path/B and A, in that order). `FNR` is the line ("record" number) in the current file, and `NR` is the overall line number, so comparing them is an easy way to tell if it's processing the first file (they'll be equal) or not (unequal).

`(NR==FNR) {b[$1]=$1}` means: for each line in the first file (/home/path/B) add the first (only) field to an array named `b`, indexed by itself.

`(NR>FNR && ! b[$2]) {print}` means: for each line in the second file (/home/path/A), if the second field (`$2`) isn't in the `b` array, print the line.